# Image Over CardView in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to make this> [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWctJ.jpg)

I only made this> [click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmFad.jpg)

I also couldn't do it with frame layout, this was my relative layout code which is in the picture;

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">

            <EditText
                android:hint="deneme"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <View
                android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_www" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I do that like designed picture?

Comment: See my post it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add elevation more than that of cardview to view with background www.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<View
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_www"
    android:elevation="10dp" />


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="deneme" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: and for the remaining parts you can play with margin and padding

Comment: Thanks i couldnt see this post for a while, it helped!

Comment: But alert dialog adds its layout which is rectangle. How can I remove it? I want to display my only cardview

Comment: I don't understand, can't see alert dialog in your question